# "hostname: Name or service not known" when hostname is written in /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname

Tags: linux

I got a problem after rebooting a device: every "sudo ..." command says "sudo: unable to resolve host *hostname here*: Name or service not known"
`hostname -i` gives `hostname: Name or service not known`. `hostname --fqdn` too.

`/etc/hostname` contains right hostname
`/etc/hosts` contains this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1   *right hostname here*
```

My only clue is that `hostname -I` returns `192.168...` ip-adress. I don't know why. Maybe because I connect through ssh-tunnel.
What will be right thing to do here?

`grep hosts: /etc/nsswitch.conf` returns:

```
grep: /etc/nsswitch.conf: Structure needs cleaning
```

Comment: Please *edit your question* to add the output of `grep hosts: /etc/nsswitch.conf` command.

Comment: @telcoM `grep: /etc/nsswitch.conf: Structure needs cleaning`

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question to put the `grep hosts: /etc/nsswitch.conf` output I requested into the actual question rather than the comments. When asked for more information or clarifications, *please edit the question* rather than adding the information in the comments, so that the information will also be preserved for future readers, as the comments will eventually expire unlike the actual questions & answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep: /etc/nsswitch.conf: Structure needs cleaning
```

This indicates your root filesystem probably needs a filesystem check: it might be corrupted. And because it's your **root** filesystem, it is likely you cannot check it without booting the system into emergency mode (that would leave the root filesystem either unmounted or in read-only mode) or booting from some external media.

Those procedures will most likely require some form of console access to the device; a SSH tunnel will probably not work because `sshd` won't be running when the root filesystem is in read-only mode.

You should **never** run a filesystem check on a filesystem that is mounted in read-write mode, unless you absolutely, positively *know* that the particular filesystem type allows it.

Since you haven't specified the nature of your "device" nor the name and version of the Linux distribution used, I cannot really give any more detailed advice.